# Should I write Orwell's '1984' in full?

Tags: writing-style, book-title

Should I write 'Nineteen Eighty-Four', when discussing George Orwell's novel in an essay, or '1984'? Is it considered unconventional, or overly colloquial to use the latter form?

This question applies for any book title consisting solely of a number, although I can't call to mind any.

Comment: If the book title really was a number, that is certainly what you should call it. There is some dispute about what Orwell actually called his book so (unless you are in one of the faculties where the dispute matters) you can use either.

Comment: Can you point me to this dispute? So far I've been struggling to find anything authoritative about the proper name.

Comment: It cannot possibly be ungrammatical as there are neither letters nor numbers in speech. Unless, of course, you consider all of spoken language ungrammatical.

Comment: You're right, what I meant to ask was whether it is conventional.

Comment: @LeoKing Either's ok. I'd use it to work in your favour word count-ways. If you're a bit under (unlikely, I suspect) then use the words. If over then use the numerals!  :)

Comment: I was about to point out that at least the 1997 movie _187_ is never written out… until I Googled it and discovered that IMDb has the title as _One Eight Seven_. Peh. :-/

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, there’s always the film *300*, which despite its name was actually about the 300 Spartans killed at Thermopylae (along with others) — ***not*** the 300 from the Sacred Band of Thebes killed at Chaeronea whom Philip famously buried with honor. Then again, the filmmakers seem to have blurred those lines themselves.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, better example. That one is given as _300_ on IMDb, too.

Comment: It seems to me that George Orwell already wrote it in full, so you don't need to write it again.

Comment: "Nineteen Eighty-Four, sometimes published as **1984** " See Wikipedia. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four

Comment: Is it opinion based to argue which form is more conventional? Surely it could be considered a matter of numbers: compare the number of papers which say '1984' vs. those which say 'Nineteen Eighty-Four'.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't matter. I'd argue the *1984* title is in more common usage nowadays. However there are *many* early covers suggesting maybe Orwell himself titled it *Nineteen Eighty-Four*.

[image][image][image]

I think you can choose whichever you please; however, *Nineteen Eighty-Four* may sound pretentious today because of its scarcity.

My favorite new cover:

[image]

Penguin Books (publishers), David Pearson (designer), 2013 [Source](http://flippies.com/adflipoff/archives/36018)

Comment: It sounds more like a real book title to write *Nineteen Eighty-Four*; otherwise there are no letters in it, which is really weird.  I am having a very hard time thinking of a book title without any words in it.  Even Richard Morgan’s novel *Black Man* was in the United States published under the title *Thirteen*, not *13*. I wonder whether you wouldn’t have a tough time publishing a book whose name were nothing but punctuation, like *#!??*, for example.

Comment: Don't forget that images are also copyright works, and attributable.

Comment: I do rather like that Penguin cover though. Clever. Now they just need to go back to printing them on real cardboard instead of that shiny coated stuff they use now.

Comment: @tchrist I bet someone will do it, and it will publish for the novelty value.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - how does one attribute a book cover? I've never done it before. I'll try t figure it out, I guess.

Comment: Well, I used the "Use this" function in Wikipedia to produce the attribution in my answer, which seems acceptable. I believe the publisher should be mentioned (since they commissioned the cover), and possibly where you got the image from.

Comment: "After publishing _Octothorpe Exclamation Point Question Mark Question Mark_ she went on to....." [ @tchrist ]

Answer (score 6):

Orwell actually called the book *Nineteen Eighty-Four,* but even that was transformed into *nineteen eighty-four* on the cover of the first edition — **and** the figure 1984 appeared as well.

[image: Nineteen Eighty-Four first edition]

There have been many editions, some featuring the title spelled out in words, others using the figures. The 1987 Penguin edition I have, first published by that house in 1954, spells out the title in words and features the original copyright attribution prominently, "Copyright 1949 by Eric Blair. All rights reserved." Given that, it's unlikely that his estate would have given permission for Penguin not to use the original title in its original form, and it should be spelled out in full.

<sub>"1984first" by George Orwell; published by Secker and Warburg (London) - Brown University Library. Image via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1984first.jpg#mediaviewer/File:1984first.jpg)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you use whatever is on the cover of *your* book.
In this case it's the number in digits.
[image]

And in this case it's spelled out:
[image]

Update:
According to [this Brown University site](http://www.brown.edu/Facilities/University_Library/libs/hay/collections/orwell/leab.html)
It says:

> 29.c. George Orwell, Nineteen Eighty-Four: A Novel printed wrappers, New York: Harcourt, Brace and Company, 1949, Advance Review Copy, First American Edition.
>   PR6029.R8 N49 1949 proof Hay Star
>
> Harcourt preferred the title "The Last Man in Europe," or at least the use of the numbers "1984", but ultimately agreed to Nineteen Eighty-Four.

From this it sounds like Orwell was pushing for it to be spelled out.

Comment: I wish that were more authoritative :/ http://mookseandgripes.com/reviews/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/1984-for-blog.jpg

Comment: That's why I said *your* book.

Comment: Don't forget that images are also copyright works, and attributable.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the dispute over the name is an integral part of the work you've been taught, I genuinely don't think it matters; given that the dispute exists, no reasonable instructor would expect you to definitively know which is the correct one, and both clearly refer to the same book.

Comment: Good point and well made.

Comment: That's an opinion, Sir.

Answer (score 2):

This history of the different editions of the book is interesting:

[History of 1984 book covers](http://flavorwire.com/190248/george-orwells-1984-a-visual-history)

In the 40s, the first american and uk versions, it was spelled out.  Then in 50s we started to see the numbers.